# location of TFS projects on different machines

Tags: tfs, directory, location, project

I have very small and quick question.

Is it neceseary for all the developers that are participating in writing a shared project through TFS, to have that project placed on the same path on each of their machines?

So for example if I have a project "TEST", and I place it in C:/Projects/, does everybody who will be mapping this project from TFS have to place it under the same path, or they can put it in different paths as long as the subfolders of the TEST project are then the same as they are at Source Control of TFS? So in our example, if someone will map that project in C:\Documents\Users\MyUser\VS2010Projects\, will it project some problem with check ins, and getting latest version(by others)?

My small project team has starnge issues lately, and I never thought it can be a problem, but I'm starting to think so and I would appriciate some response from someone who has some expierience in that field.

Lucas

Comment: TFS (and indeed most source control systems) allow users to store their repositories anywhere.  However, you do have to be careful that the *code you're writing* doesn't expect a specific path.  What are your "strange issues?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up your source control paths & your solutions properly this shouldn't be an issue. 
Let's say that you have a `project1` that uses a lib named `core`.
 If you set this as follows users can map wherever they want in their local PCs in the content under `$/.../Program1`:

```
$/../Project1
      /SharedSources
          /Lib_branch
              Lib.csproj
      /Sources
          /Project1A
              Project1A.csproj
          /Project1B
              Project1B.csproj
          Project1.sln
```

If you are set as follows:

```
$/../Lib
     Lib.csproj
$/../Project1
     /Project1A
         Project1A.csproj
     /Project1B
         Project1B.csproj
      Project1.sln
```

things are more challenging, since - in order for the solution to work in each workstation - *both*`$/../Lib` & `$/../Project1` have to be mapped in the same level.